# Authenticate single user in Google Calendar api

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm working on a system which allows you to schedule events using Google's calendar API. However, this is going to be for a small company's internal use and they only need to use a single Google account (ie one for the entire company) so that everyone can have access to the exact same events.

I've implemented the calendar API and scheduling functionality (in PHP btw), but when authenticating a user they are able to login with any Google account, including their personal ones. They should only be able to authenticate with the company account so that events don't get scheduled into personal accounts.

What I thought about doing was checking the authenticated account's email address to see if it matches with the company one, and if it doesn't an error will be displayed telling them they are on the wrong account.

This would work, but it seems like a very inefficient and ugly solution (especially considering that I'd probably need to use the Google+ API to get their email address).

What would be the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are authenticating using Google's OAuth2 mechanism, you actually must register your app in the Google API console (https://code.google.com/apis/console), and provide the client secret, client id, authorization uri, and so forth to your app.  Under this authentication mechanism, your users have no choice but to authenticate with the account registered in the API console, and hence there is no problem with them authenticating with "other" accounts.

Google's advice on using alternate (non OAuth) authentication means is as follows:

> AuthSub and ClientLogin are Google's proprietary authorization APIs, available as an alternative to OAuth for most Google APIs. If possible, you should avoid using these services. If you already have applications that use them, you should migrate to the recommended options described above.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/overview

Additionally, "ClientLogin" & "AuthSub" have actually been deprecated:

> Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

> Important: AuthSub has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub

My advice would be to migrate to OAuth2, and the problem solves itself.  If you are using one of the 2 deprecated methods, you may well have to formulate your own "very inefficient and ugly solution", as you said.

And the Google Calendar docs are actually pretty extensive:  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Are they really easy?  No.  But one thing they aren't is scarce.  The PHP client library is here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

With a PHP sample here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php

Be aware that most of the Google docs for the calendar assume the use of OAuth2.

Comment: Paul...if you still around...I would love bounce an issue off you...re OAuth2 and google calendar.